# PHP: Composer auto-load not working

Tags: php, composer-php

Actually Iam new to PHP. I am running this from a nearly empty folder (actually following along a Lara-casts tutorial: Design a Fluent API with TDD).

My directory structure looks like

- src

  - Expression.php
- tests

  - ExpressionTest.php
- vendor
- composer.json
- composer.lock

Inside composer.json:

```
{    
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Inside ExpressionTest.php:

```
class ExpressionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_finds_a_string()
    {
        $regex = Expression::make()->find('www');

        $this->assertRegExp($regex, 'www');
    }
}
```

Inside Expression.php

```
<?php

class Expression
{

}
```

I then run composer dump-autoload and run phpunit but I still get:

```
 "Fatal error: Class 'Expression' not found in 
C:\Users\nobis\code\testing2\tests\ExpressionTest.php on line 8"
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? My understanding of Composer is very basic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit does not know about Composer natively, therefore without configuring PHPUnit, it will not know about your autoloader setup.

try running PHPunit with `--bootstrap vendor/autoload.php` to tell it to load with your autoload file.

If that does not work, check your namespace value in your Composer configuration (i.e. `"": "src/"` might need to change.)

Comment: Thanks. I also had to specify that PHPUnit was in the folder's vendor folder:
    ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php

But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I only thought to include the flag portion, not the entire required command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the autoloader at the top of your test. It is typically at

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

You can also add a phpunit.xml file to your tell it where the autoloader is then it will run it before every test:

```
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/5.2/phpunit.xsd"
    bootstrap="/path/to/bootstrap.php"

</phpunit>
```